# Check user name availability from firebase in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently stuck on checking unique username in the sign up(on firebase) in react. My goal is that 
1. when the user input the username, the function checkNameAvalaible go to the firebase database and check if the name exists.
2.if the name exists set the state of usernameavalaible to false, and set it to true if name works
3.disable the submit button of the sign up if the usernameavalaible is false.
4.If the username is taken, use helper text in textfield to alert the current user.
I am stuck with the if statement, I tried a few times and it is not working here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import { db} from "../firebase";
import "./auth.css";
import * as routes from "../constants/routes";
import { SignInLink } from "./SignIn";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const SignUpPage = ({ history }) => (
  <div align="center" className="SignUpBox">
    <h1>SignUp</h1>
    <SignUpForm history={history} />
    <SignInLink />
  </div>
);

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  username: "",
  name: "",
  email: "",
  passwordOne: "",
  passwordTwo: "",

  error: null
};
const byPropKey = (propertyName, value) => () => ({
  [propertyName]: value
});



class SignUpForm extends Component {

  state = { ...INITIAL_STATE };

  //   checkPassword() {
  //     if(!this.state.passwordOne || this.state.passwordOne !==    this.state.passwordTwo){
  //        this.setState({error:"passwords do not match"});
  //    }
  //    else {
  //        this.setState({error:null});
  //    }
  // }



  onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { email, passwordOne, name, username } = this.state;

    auth
      .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email,
        passwordOne,
        name,
        username
      )
      .then(authUser => {
        this.setState(() => ({ ...INITIAL_STATE }));
        this.props.history.push(routes.HOME);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState(byPropKey("error", error));
      });
  };

  render() {
    var usernameAvalaible
    const {
      username,
      name,
      email,
      passwordOne,
      passwordTwo,
      error
    } = this.state;

    checkNameAvalaible(){
      if (db.doc(`/users/${username}`).get().exists){
        this.setState{usernameAvalaible:false};
      }
      else{
        this.setState{usernameAvalaible:true};
      }

    };


    const isInvalid =
      passwordOne !== passwordTwo ||
      passwordOne === "" ||
      email === "" ||
      name === "" ||
      username === ""|| usernameAvalaible===false;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <TextField
          name="Username"
          id="standard-secondary"
          label="User name"
          color="primary"
          value={username}
      onChange={event =>
        this.setState(byPropKey("username", event.target.value))
      }
      type="text"
    />
    <TextField
      name="name"
      value={name}
      id="standard-secondary"
      label="Full name"
      color="primary"
      onChange={event =>
        this.setState(byPropKey("name", event.target.value))
      }
      type="text"
    />
    <TextField
      name="email"
      value={email}
      id="standard-secondary"
      label="Email Address"
      color="primary"
      onChange={event =>
        this.setState(byPropKey("email", event.target.value))
      }
      type="email"
    />
    <TextField
      name="password"
      value={passwordOne}
      id="standard-secondary"
      label="Password"
      color="primary"
      onChange={event =>
        this.setState(byPropKey("passwordOne", event.target.value))
      }
      type="password"
    />
    <TextField
      name="ConfirmPassword"
      value={passwordTwo}
      id="standard-secondary"
      label="Comfirm Password"
      color="primary"
      onChange={event =>
        this.setState(byPropKey("passwordTwo", event.target.value))
      }
      type="password"
    />

    <br />
    <br />

    <Button
      type="submit"
      disabled={isInvalid}
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
    >
      Sign Up
    </Button>

    {error && <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{error.message}</p>}
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const SignUpLink = () => (
  <p>
    Don't have an account? <Link to={routes.SIGN_UP}>Sign Up</Link>
  </p>
);

export default SignUpPage;

export { SignUpForm, SignUpLink };
```

Comment: Share your codes instead of pictures!

Comment: My bad, thanks a lot

Comment: im a vuejs user so i' not particularly useful for the react part. however, you may want to 1) use debounce (lodash has one) so the client won't check the username on every keystroke; 2) use a firebase function (express api or https.onRequest or maybe graphql) instead of querying the rtdb directly;